# linq outer apply with like statement

Tags: linq

I have a main table workspend like this:

```
Description    Date         Timespend
TH work x      2018-12-28   3 hrs
NL work y      2018-12-28   2 hrs
UK work z      2018-12-30   5 hrs
```

and a table with customers

```
CustomerNo     SearchTerms
C0001          Germany DEU DE
C0002          Netherlands NLD NL
C0003          United Kingdom UK
```

Now I want to write for my report a linq query that shows the main table with the customerNo if it can finds it. 
In SQL i would write something like

```
SELECT workspend.*,CustomerNo FROM workspend w
OUTER APPLY (SELECT top 1 * from customers c
WHERE c.SearchTerms LIKE '% ' + SUBSTRING(w.Description,1,2)) x
WHERE w.Date BETWEEN '2018-12-28' AND '2018-12-29'
```

The result would then be like

```
Description    Date         Timespend    CustomerNo     SearchTerms
TH work x      2018-12-28   3 hrs        NULL           NULL
NL work y      2018-12-28   2 hrs        C0002          Netherlands NLD NL
```

Is this possible in linq?
Thanks in advance

Comment: "main table with the customerNo if it can finds it" - didn't quite understand that part ?

Comment: Please show a class model. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), and show your own first efforts so we see at which stage of the process you need help.

Comment: You should be able to use two `from` with a `where` using `Contains`.

Comment: Make that `EndsWith`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my translation. LINQ to SQL will translate this to an `OUTER APPLY`:

```
var ans = from w in workspend
          where DateTime.Parse("2018-12-28") <= w.Date && w.Date <= DateTime.Parse("2018-12-29")
          from c in (from cs in customers where cs.SearchTerms.LastIndexOf(w.Description.Substring(0, 2)) == cs.SearchTerms.Length-2 select cs).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new {
              w,
              c.CustomerNo
          };
```

LINQ to SQL/Entities unfortunately can't translate `Contains` or `EndsWith` if you are using a server value (sadly which would have been easy to put in) so you must use `LastIndexOf` to fake it.

You can also use a sub-query which will translate to a SQL Sub-query in the `SELECT`:

```
var ans2 = from w in workspend
           where DateTime.Parse("2018-12-28") <= w.Date && w.Date <= DateTime.Parse("2018-12-29")
           select new {
               w,
               (from cs in customers where cs.SearchTerms.LastIndexOf(w.Description.Substring(0, 2)) == cs.SearchTerms.Length - 2 select cs).FirstOrDefault().CustomerNo
           };
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified it a little bit by using LastIndexOf(

Comment: @jkRegistraties That makes sense. I'll change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I have understood your Question correctly. You can use GroupJoin with a Custom Comparer to achieve the result.

For example, for the data

```
var listMain = new List<MainTable>{
    new MainTable{Description = "TH work x", Date = new DateTime(2018,12,28), TimeSpend = "3 hrs"},
    new MainTable{Description = "NL work x", Date = new DateTime(2018,12,29), TimeSpend = "2 hrs"},
    new MainTable{Description = "UK work x", Date = new DateTime(2018,12,30), TimeSpend = "5 hrs"},
    };


var listCustomers = new List<Customers>
    {
    new Customers{CustomerNo="C0001", SearchTerms = "Germany DEU DE"},
    new Customers{CustomerNo="C0002", SearchTerms = "Netherlands NLD NL"},
    new Customers{CustomerNo="C0003", SearchTerms = "United Kingdom UK"},
    };
```

Where MainTable and Customer is defined as

```
public class MainTable
{
    public string Description{get;set;}
    public DateTime Date{get;set;}
    public string TimeSpend {get;set;}
}


public class Customers
{
    public string CustomerNo{get;set;}
    public string SearchTerms{get;set;}
}
```

You can query using Linq as

```
var result = listMain.Where(x=>x.Date >= new DateTime(2018,12,28) && x.Date<new DateTime(2018,12,30)).GroupJoin(listCustomers,
                    x=>x.Description,
                    y=>y.SearchTerms,
                    (x,y)=> new {Main= x, Customers = y},
                    new ContainsEqualityComparer())
                    .Select(g=> new 
                    {
                       Description = g.Main.Description, 
                       Date=g.Main.Date,
                       TimeSpend=g.Main.TimeSpend,
                       CustomerNo=g.Customers.Any() ? g.Customers.First().CustomerNo: null,
                       SearchTerms=g.Customers.Any() ? g.Customers.First().SearchTerms:null
                    });
```

Where CustomEqualityComparer is defined as

```
class ContainsEqualityComparer: IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string right, string left) 
    { 
    return right.Contains(left.Substring(0,2)); 
    }
    public int GetHashCode(string obj) { return 0; }
}
```

Output is shown below

[image]